# Skybox affecting sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine

The default skybox affects the sprites colour.  I'm not sure how to stop this from happening.  You can see below that the outline of the sprite is brown instead of grey.

If I set the main camera clear flags and background to Solid colour & black respectively, the brown from the skybox still shows through.

I'm not sure what information would be useful for others to assist me with this, so if there is any info I can add, just let me know and I'll update accordingly.

[image: Example sprite]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window->Rendering->Lighting Settings

Under Debug Settings, select Generate Lighting.
De-select Auto Generate.
From the Baked Lightmaps set Lighting Data Asset to None.
Remove generated Lighting from the project.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing here is alpha blending, your 'outline' pixels have low alpha, so when rendered Unity will blend their color with the background. It generally represents transparency, but in this case it's behaving as a kind of anti-aliasing (it makes your sprites look smoother and less pixely) In that sense, it's working as intended. Look at your sprites at normal resolution and you'll notice they should look good.

If you prefer the pixelated look and really don't want this behaviour, you need to edit your sprites to have full alpha on those pixels.

Comment: I already realise that they have low alpha, this is why I added the part about replacing the skybox with a solid colour, I'd expect the solid colour to show through the sprite rather than the skybox that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I would at least like to be able to add a solid colour background which overrides the default brown skybox, without a horizon so that I can control the alpha blending on the sprite.  At the moment, when I add a background of my own choosing, the sprite still takes up the brown from the skybox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Empty's answer: 
Are you using the standard shader? That shader uses the environment map as an ambient color on top of the diffuse color (albedo). This is perfectly normal behaviour and makes colors of everything blend nicely with each other. (with an orange sky white objects will look onage-ish. ) This is part of "physically correct lighting" (PBL). It is not at all physically correct, but it comes close enough for now. 
If you don't want the environment to affect the colro that mucha you could either alter the environment map to a less dramatic color (normal blue/white sky) or use an unlit shader/material.

Comment: I would be happy with just a solid white background.  I'm not going to change the sprite, as then all sprites would need changing.

Comment: If this is the actual issue then you can fix it by changing the ambient source from skybox to gradient or color in: Window->Lighting->Scene->Environmental Lighting->Source, then you can override it. That said, if it's a sprite shader (it looks like a sprite shader) ambient lighting has no effect.